# Using php if statement within wrapped Wordpress Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

I'm trying to load this php function within this wrapped shortcode but it doesnt work. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<?php
$my_tabs = '
[accordions title="" disabled="false" active="false" autoheight="false" collapsible="true"]
[accordion title="SPECIFICATIONS"] ' . if( function_exists( 'wpsc_the_custom_fields' ) ) wpsc_the_custom_fields() . ' [/accordion]
[/accordions] ';
echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the shortcut condition notation called the `Ternary operator` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

```
<?php
$my_tabs = '
[accordions title="" disabled="false" active="false" autoheight="false" collapsible="true"]
[accordion title="SPECIFICATIONS"] ' . ( function_exists( 'wpsc_the_custom_fields' ) ) ? wpsc_the_custom_fields() : '' . ' [/accordion]
[/accordions] ';
echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
```

?>

Comment: This fixed the php issues but now the function I want within my accordion is displaying outside of it. Above it to be specific. How can I fix this? Basically I only want the content to display on click hence the shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$my_tabs = '
[accordions title="" disabled="false" active="false" autoheight="false" collapsible="true"]
[accordion title="SPECIFICATIONS"] ' . (function_exists( 'wpsc_the_custom_fields' ) ? wpsc_the_custom_fields() : '') . ' [/accordion]
[/accordions] ';
echo do_shortcode( $my_tabs );
?>
```

Comment: Ok thank you! This fixed the php issues but now the function I want within my accordion is displaying outside of it. Above it to be specific. How can I fix this? Basically I only want the content to display on click hence the shortcode. Is there a way to echo the function within the shortcode?

Comment: does your function `wpsc_the_custom_fields()` `echo` its output or do u use `return` to return the output ?

Comment: /* Start of: Storefront */

    function wpsc_the_custom_fields( $args = null ) {

   global $wpsc_cf;

   $position = wpsc_cf_get_option( 'position' );
  if( $args )
   wpsc_cf_get_value( $args );
  else if( $position == 'manual' )
   wpsc_cf_html_product();

  }

 function wpsc_cf_show_title() {

  global $wpsc_cf;

  $display_title = wpsc_cf_get_option( 'display_title' );
  return $display_title;

 }

Comment: Im pretty sure it uses return